# error in url(urltext,....,method="libcurl"):cannot open connection when to Knit wrod

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

> Error in url(urltext,...method="libcurl'): Cannot open connection Calls: ...eval->eval->randomNumbers->getConnection->url

I am trying to knit word the Rmd file. Running some tests on Random Numbers from [`random.org`](https://www.random.org). But I keep getting this error message, any troubleshooting suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**NOT AN ANSWER**

You haven't really provided anything to help folks debug but:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(rvest)
"https://www.random.org/integers/?num=100&min=1&max=100&col=5&base=10&format=html&rnd=new" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("pre.data") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  strsplit("[\t\n]") %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  as.numeric()
```
````

works fine for me.